# Is this function row-major?

Tags: math, graphics, matrix, 3d

I've been staring at this stuff so long my head is in a blurred daze but I think I'm getting it. I'm using a matrix library, and a matrix has its data stored as:

```
struct Matrix4{
    vec4 x;
    vec4 y;
    vec4 z;
    vec4 w;
..... functions
}
```

A `vec4` is simply a struct with its data as:

```
T x;
T y;
T z;
T w;
```

(`T` is typically a `float`)

The key question is probably answered by this:

```
    Matrix4 operator * (const Matrix4& b) const
{
    Matrix4 m;
    m.x.x = x.x * b.x.x + x.y * b.y.x + x.z * b.z.x + x.w * b.w.x;
    m.x.y = x.x * b.x.y + x.y * b.y.y + x.z * b.z.y + x.w * b.w.y;
    m.x.z = x.x * b.x.z + x.y * b.y.z + x.z * b.z.z + x.w * b.w.z;
    m.x.w = x.x * b.x.w + x.y * b.y.w + x.z * b.z.w + x.w * b.w.w;
    m.y.x = y.x * b.x.x + y.y * b.y.x + y.z * b.z.x + y.w * b.w.x;
    m.y.y = y.x * b.x.y + y.y * b.y.y + y.z * b.z.y + y.w * b.w.y;
    m.y.z = y.x * b.x.z + y.y * b.y.z + y.z * b.z.z + y.w * b.w.z;
    m.y.w = y.x * b.x.w + y.y * b.y.w + y.z * b.z.w + y.w * b.w.w;
    m.z.x = z.x * b.x.x + z.y * b.y.x + z.z * b.z.x + z.w * b.w.x;
    m.z.y = z.x * b.x.y + z.y * b.y.y + z.z * b.z.y + z.w * b.w.y;
    m.z.z = z.x * b.x.z + z.y * b.y.z + z.z * b.z.z + z.w * b.w.z;
    m.z.w = z.x * b.x.w + z.y * b.y.w + z.z * b.z.w + z.w * b.w.w;
    m.w.x = w.x * b.x.x + w.y * b.y.x + w.z * b.z.x + w.w * b.w.x;
    m.w.y = w.x * b.x.y + w.y * b.y.y + w.z * b.z.y + w.w * b.w.y;
    m.w.z = w.x * b.x.z + w.y * b.y.z + w.z * b.z.z + w.w * b.w.z;
    m.w.w = w.x * b.x.w + w.y * b.y.w + w.z * b.z.w + w.w * b.w.w;
    return m;
}
```

In a column-major system, the `operator*` should assume that the top row of the matrix on the left is *not* in contiguous memory, since it stores the first element of each column vector. This function is clearly treating the first row of the left-hand matrix (the `*this` matrix) as contiguous, thus implying this is a row-major matrix library, right?

**After looking at this stuff for so long, I gather that the only way to really determine if a library is column-major or row-major is to look how it handles multiplication with respect to how it lays out its data.**

While not likely necessary to diagnose my question, the translation matrix the library provides for a 3d translation transformation places the `x, y, z` data in the final `vec4`. But this data could be in this location in either a column-major or row-major system so it's likely a trivial piece of evidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column vs Row major is really a matter of interpretation, since if these were column-major matrices, the matrix multiplication code would look exactly the same. i.e., the vec4 members could simply be *interpreted* as columns.

That said, I consider column-major matrices to be evil and wrong, because that's how I learnt linear algebra:) A vector is a 4x1 matrix (a column) and a vector transform is: 4x4 x 4x1 = 4x1. The outer terms give the dimensions, the inner terms make it legal. 1x4 x 4x4 = 1x4 is legal, but has no place in a well-ordered universe. Like left-handed coordinate spaces.

I've always liked [these](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/math/matrix/column-vec.html) posts from various SGI alumni.

Comment: Consider the function as you write code. A*B can only use rows from A. Therefore the vec4 must be a row.

Comment: @Fellowshee - Q.E.D. It appears you've answered your own question then.

Comment: I was looking for confirmation of this, and your answer seemed to suggest I was wrong.

Comment: @Fellowshee - No, I was over-thinking it, and looking for ambiguities that weren't really there. I got it wrong. You are right - including the part about staring too long at something.